# Stripe: add free days to a subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to add free days to an active subscription on Stripe?

I'd like to do it in order to create a referral program: when a user refers someone, he gets 10 free days.

I think a good way to do it would be to update the `current_period_end` var, but I can't find how to do it in the doc.

For example:

- Bob is subscribed and will be charged on the 15th of this month
- He refers Alice
- He gets 10 free days on his account, and his next billing date is now on the 25th

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest you could do would be apply some sort of credit to her account, so instead of 10 free days, it's earn (33% of monthly fee) per referral.

Comment: Just to add to this incase someone google's it, they way to handle would be to set "trial_end" to the next bill date, and set prorate = false

Comment: Thank you @MatthewArkin.
People don't understand Matthew answer for the 1st time like can see more detail here: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/billing-cycle